# Calculating probability using mean value

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a random three-dimensional random variable such that the marginal distribution of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are equal, and $Pr(X_1+X_2+X_3=9)=Pr(\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)\ge0)=1$.

Suppose we put in a box $X_1$ red balls, $X_2$ blue balls and $X_3$ green balls, and we choose a ball randomly. What's the probablity we get a red ball?

I understand that $\Bbb E[X_1]=\Bbb E[X_2] = \Bbb E[X_3]=3$, but I don't understand how I can use it to calculate the probabilty?

Comment: Since you have $X_1$ red balls, hence $X_1$ positive events among 9 events with the same probability of occuring, $Pr(redball)=E[X_1/9]=E[X_1]/9=3/9=1/3$ should solve the problem.

Comment: Why is the probabilty $E[X_1/9]$? It sounds right but what justifies it?

Comment: What is the probability of picking a red ball if there are $X_1$ red balls and $9-X_1$ non-red balls in a box ? Then you notice that this probability is a linear function of $X_1$ (very important !) and you use the fact that taking expected value commutes with linear transformations.